# What to put constraints for image?

Tags: ios, constraints

Does anyone know what constraints shall I add to a small image that should remain on the top center and it remains this way either if I view it in portrait or landscape? Mind you, I'm going to look that same for all iPhone so the width should be 600.. please? :)

p.s I tried to put all options (not really) but it didnt work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center horizontally in container and top space to top layout.

Comment: It didn't work, I've chosen (Top Space to Container) and (Top Space to Container) if that's what you mean, it worked because it is in the top center of the UIView but it's bigger that iPhone4, it's width = 600

Comment: I added a ScrollView then pin it as the first part in the picture and added a UIView and pin it as the second part of the picture http://oi63.tinypic.com/ibe8es.jpg then I added the image.